# how to remove all the rows in a dataframe having 0's and Err:502 in various columns

Tags: r

I have a data frame ss that has 26 columns and 100000 rows. in the data frame, there are values both positive and negative values, 0's and Err:502.

I need to remove all the rows in the data frame having 0's and Err:502

here I am giving the sample data frame

```
Dataframe: ss
A    B            C          D      E
C    -1.3456    1.232    23.5453    0
B    56.258     0         -1.00023  234.556
D    43.22435   324.5657 1.00032    345.7
E    Err:502    341.4656 1.9823     32.12
E    0          Err:502  2324       asd
F    0.0004342  234      12         78.31214
F    dfgd       2.313    0.000487   0.12345



ss <- ss[apply(ss[,-1], 1, function(x) !all(x==0)),]
ss[ss != 0, ]



the expected data frame ss should be like as follows 
A         B       C       D      E
D    43.22435   324.5657 1.00032    345.7
F    0.0004342  234      12         78.31214
F    dfgd       2.313    0.000487   0.12345
```

but the code i used is not working. 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rowSums` in base R

```
df[rowSums(df == 0 | df == "Err:502") == 0, ]

# A         B        C         D        E
#3 D  43.22435 324.5657  1.000320    345.7
#6 F 0.0004342      234 12.000000 78.31214
#7 F      dfgd    2.313  0.000487  0.12345
```

---

Or with `apply`

```
df[apply(df, 1, function(x) all(x != 0 & x != "Err:502")), ]
```

Comment: in the apply function, if we use '&' or '|' in rowSum, this means 'and' condition. so does it removes the rows  having  both but not either?!

Comment: @Kumar yes, both of them remove rows which would have either or both of 0 and "Err:502".

Comment: so, this will check each row and remove the rows having 0's and Err:502. what if we want to remove rows based on 3rd and 5th column. how can we specify ? can we use df[apply(df[, c(3,5)], 1, function(x) all(x != 0 & x != "Err:502")), ] ....?

Comment: onemore thing... if we want to remove rows having 'NAN' along with 0's and Err:502, can we use this ...df[apply(df, 1, function(x) all(x != 0 & x != "Err:502" & X != NAN)), ]

Comment: @Kumar if you want to check only for column 3 and 5 with `NA` you can do `df[apply(df[c(3, 5)], 1, function(x) all(x != 0 & x != "Err:502" & !is.na(x))), ]`

Answer (score 2):

we can use `filter_at`

```
library(dplyr)
ss %>%
    filter_at(-1, all_vars(!.  %in% c(0, "Err:502")))
#   A         B        C         D        E
#1 D  43.22435 324.5657  1.000320    345.7
#2 F 0.0004342      234 12.000000 78.31214
#3 F      dfgd    2.313  0.000487  0.12345
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
ss[!Reduce(`|`, lapply(ss[-1], `%in%`, c(0, "Err:502"))),]
```

NOTE: Both methods are efficient compared to `apply`

The OP's code with `apply` can be corrected as

```
ss[apply(ss, 1, function(x) all(! x %in% c(0, "Err:502"))), ]
#  A         B        C         D        E
#3 D  43.22435 324.5657  1.000320    345.7
#6 F 0.0004342      234 12.000000 78.31214
#7 F      dfgd    2.313  0.000487  0.12345
```

#### data

```
ss <- structure(list(A = c("C", "B", "D", "E", "E", "F", "F"), B = c("-1.3456", 
"56.258", "43.22435", "Err:502", "0", "0.0004342", "dfgd"), C = c("1.232", 
"0", "324.5657", "341.4656", "Err:502", "234", "2.313"), D = c(23.5453, 
-1.00023, 1.00032, 1.9823, 2324, 12, 0.000487), E = c("0", "234.556", 
"345.7", "32.12", "asd", "78.31214", "0.12345")),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -7L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
df <- as.data.table(df)
out <- df[df[, !Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD, function(x) x ==0 | x == "Err:502"))]]
```